# How to convert RTF ANSI to HTML using Javascript or Any React text editor which support RTF format

Tags: javascript, reactjs, rtf, rich-text-editor, draftjs

I have to render RTF ANSI format data in the React Draft Wysiwyg / any other react editor.

we are getting API response as RTF ANSI format, which I have render in the rich text editor after any changes in the editor text, I have to covert into RTF and save into the DB, I haven't found any solution or Editor which will meet my requirements.

Example RTF String: `'{\rtf1ansiansicpg1252deff0\nouicompat{\fonttbl{\f0\fnil\fcharset0 Arial;}{\f1\fnil\fcharset0 Arial Black;}{\f2\fnil\fcharset0 Courier New;}{\f3\fnil\fcharset0 Georgia;}{\f4\fnil\fcharset0 Tahoma;}{\f5\fnil\fcharset0 Times New Roman;}{\f6\fnil\fcharset0 Verdana;}}{colortbl ;}{pard\fs34qc Hello Worldsb70par}}'`

**This is how it look after render in the rich text editor.**

[image]

I have tried with many converters but no help.

Example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-5avkvj?file=src/index.js

Thanks in advance.